# Azure Devops Rules for WorkItems

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

We have created a field in all Work Items, named "Manager" to assign the Manager of the developer/tester, to whom the work item is assigned to. Now that person in the Manager field is not getting any email Notification when the assignee updates the work item.
Tried setting the notification, but creating notification for every work item is not feasible.
I tried with setting rules, but doesn't seem to have the right conditions and actions available.
I read about third party tools like power automate. Before jumping into that solution, I would like to know if this can be achieved with the existing configuration settings in Azure Devops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if this can be achieved with the existing
> configuration settings in Azure Devops

I am afraid that azure devops currently does not provide built-in configuration settings to achieve this requirement.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.